# Learning concepts in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, learning

Apologies for the soft question, but I was wondering whether it is a good idea, in mathematics, to learn/study things simply for the sake of studying it. A very good example comes from category theory. I've seen many people here on MSE who wish to study category theory for the sake of studying the abstractness and the richness of category theory. While pure category theory is fun, it was built to be applied, like in algebraic topology and homotopy theory.

> Is it alright to have this attitude when studying "abstract concepts" (like (higher) category theory)? How about when publishing research? Does research always have to have some applications to something known previously?

Comment: I think this should be CW, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: I think you should take core courses and a separate course in category at a university and not by self-taught.

Comment: @ah-huh-moment. That's possible if you are in a unversity, not if you're not. I'm not. I'm not referring specifically to category theory (I have a firm grip over category theory and related subjects like AG and homotopy theory.), but rather to "abstract concepts" in general, and research, of course.

Comment: I think you risk wasting time to learn on your own. You really should go to a university and take formal classes there in these courses. Its the only way out. You need a teacher.

Comment: @ah-huh-moment. Why do you say so? Is it not possible to learn something on your own? (If you would really like to know, I have a mentor at UCLA, who gives me advice on my research.)

Comment: You need to be formally enrolled at a school like the one you mentioned where you have a reseach professor who supervises you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good work (for instance, it which are obtained new and beautiful results) is worth to be published. As a mathematician and a referee, I am pro such works. I think that the essence of development concerns with creation of new things. I think that a theory has own growth and development, and, therefore it is not restricted to serve to applications. And a study is a form of own development of a mathematician. Now I step back, and Alfred Tarski give  the [final remarks](http://www.ditext.com/tarski/tarski2.html#sec23).